# How to test post route in fastify?

Tags: javascript, testing, fastify

I'm using fastify-cli. I already created a routed post. Its work normally when I call it from Postman, but not working when I call it from test command. It says *FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE*. Where is my mistake?

```
const UserCreate = {
    email: 'email@email.com',
    password: bcrypt.hashSync('password', salt),
    name: 'User Fullname',
    username: 'cooluser',
    initial: 'U',
    roleId: 1,
    status: 'active'
}


test(`create User`, async (t) => {
    const app = build(t)

    const res = await app.inject({
        url: '/administrator/user',
        method: 'POST',
        payload: JSON.stringify(UserCreate),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    console.log(`res.payload`, res.payload)
    t.equal(JSON.parse(res.payload).code, 200)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I just need to change `payload: JSON.stringify(UserCreate)` to `body: UserCreate`. So I don't needto stringify usercreate object to text. and also I get data from body, so I also need to change to `body` instead of `payload`.

test code should be like this:

```
test(`create User`, async (t) => {
    const app = build(t)

    const res = await app.inject({
        url: '/administrator/user',
        method: 'POST',
        body: UserCreate,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    console.log(`res.payload`, res.payload)
    t.equal(JSON.parse(res.payload).code, 200)
})
```